# I want to pass array object inside array subdocument in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

**Here is my Schema**

I am trying to add replies array inside answers array. If someone answers a question and if someone wants to reply on the given answer

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    postedBy: {
      type: ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "User",
    },
    question: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    photo: {
      data: String,
      required: false,
    },
    answers: [
      {
        userId: { type: ObjectId, ref: "User" },
        answerType: {
          data: String,
          required: false,
        },
        answer: String,
        replies: [
          {
            userId: { type: ObjectId, ref: "User" },
            reply: String,
            replyType: {
              data: String,
              required: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    questionType: {
      data: String,
      required: false,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
      default: Date.now,
    },
  },

  { timeStamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Question", questionSchema);
```

Here is my Controller method

```
exports.postReply = (req, res) => {
  const reply = req.body.reply || "";
  const userId = req.user._id || "";
  const answerId = req.body.answerId || "";

  Question.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: answerId },
    ({ $push: { answers: { answer: { replies: { reply, userId } } } } },
    { new: true }),
    (err, newReply) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
          error: errorHandler(err),
        });
      } else {
        res.json({
          msg: "Reply posted successfully",
          newReply,
        });
      }
    }
  );
};
```

I feel I am going wrong on the findOneAndUpdate method. I am getting no error on the console but newReply comes null. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the parentesis for in front of curly braces --> `...({ $push: ...` and after `{ new: true }),` <-- it should look like this `...AndUpdate(answerId, { $push: { answers: ... } }, { new: true }, (err, newR...`

Comment: If you try this code `console.log( ({ $push: { answers: { answer: { replies: { reply, userId } } } } }, { new: true }) );` you will see that it logs `{ new: true }` so you are not pushing anything into document.

Comment: @Molda i removed the the bracket but it's showing error 400

Comment: So have you tried to log the error? The error 400 you see is from your code `if (err){ res.status(400)...` so try `console.log(err);`

Comment: Yes debugged it and also added console.log(err) and it's showing null

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using the $addToSet instead of the $push operator as you are adding a document to the array. (see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/).
If you want to add more than one document to the array, refer also to the $each operator together with $addToSet.

So your coding can look similiar to this (note: the variable 'yourDocument' is the document you want to add):

```
Question.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: answerId },
    { $addToSet: { answers: yourDocument } },
    { new: true },
    (err, newReply) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
          error: errorHandler(err),
        });
      } else {
        res.json({
          msg: "Reply posted successfully",
          newReply,
        });
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: You still have `)` after  `{ new: true })` :)

Comment: @stefOb hey I tried your answer but it's coming 400 bad request

Comment: @Molda Also my route is this---> router.post("/community/postReply", requireSignin, postReply);

Do I need to add :answerId after postReply since it's an array and I'll requiring it at exports as params?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clearly the parentesis around
`({ $push: { answers: { answer: { replies: { reply, userId } } } } }, { new: true })`

Doing this `console.log( ({a:1}, {b:2}) );` will log `{b: 2}` which means you are doing this

```
Question.findByIdAndUpdate( { _id: answerId }, { new: true }, (err, newReply) => {
```

So remove the parentesis and you should be good

```
Question.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: answerId },
    { $push: { answers: { answer: { replies: { reply, userId } } } } },
    { new: true },
    (err, newReply) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
          error: errorHandler(err),
        });
      } else {
        res.json({
          msg: "Reply posted successfully",
          newReply,
        });
      }
    }
  );
```